# Rotate a point by another point in 2D

Tags: c#, math, rotation, angle

I want to know how to work out the new co-ordinates for a point when rotated by an angle relative to another point.

I have a block arrow and want to rotate it by an angle theta relative to a point in the middle of the base of the arrow.

This is required to allow me to draw a polygon between 2 onscreen controls. I can't use and rotate an image.

From what I have considered so far what complicates the matter further is that the origin of a screen is in the top left hand corner.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

If you rotate point `(px, py)` around point `(ox, oy)` by angle `theta` you'll get:

```
p'x = cos(theta) * (px-ox) - sin(theta) * (py-oy) + ox
p'y = sin(theta) * (px-ox) + cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy
```

Comment: Do you have the 3D version in memory too? :)

Comment: It depends on which library you're using for the trig functions. In C, you need to pass in radians.

Comment: to convert in radians : value * Math.PI / 180;

Comment: The answer to the general 3D problem is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188876/rotation-matrix-given-angle-and-point-in-x-y-z/).

Comment: This is great code ... but it is not actually in C#!

Answer (score 8):

If you are using GDI+ to do that, you can use `Transform` methods of the `Graphics` object:

```
graphics.TranslateTransform(point of origin);
graphics.RotateTransform(rotation angle);
```

Then draw the actual stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `System.Windows.Media` namespace available, then you can use the built in transformations:

```
    using System.Windows.Media;

    var transform = new RotateTransform() {Angle = angleInDegrees, CenterX = center.X, CenterY = center.Y};
    var transformedPoint = transform.Transform(point);
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes a layout transform command on your image in the WPF, and rotates it the degree you want.

```
progress_image.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(90);
```