# CGPoints and UIViews

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, rotation, cgpoint

Is it possible to place a CGPoint inside of a UIView as a subview so that when I rotate my UIView, the CGPoint rotates with it.

Answer (score 1):

A CGPoint is a logical construct, not a graphical. With that said, the following will produce a point rotated around another (called point). This may not apply directly, but should give you some direction. The key is CGAffineTransform.

```
CGAffineTransform translateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTransation(point.x, point.y);
CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
CGAffineTransform customTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat( CGAffineTransformInvert(translateTransform), rotateTransform), translateTransform);
newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(initialPoint, customTransform);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CGPoint` (like `CGSize` or `CGRect`) are C structures and are not supposed to be "drawable". I mean that they are just math representation of coordinates or geometric "stuff" then is not possibile to append them in your display tree.

If you need to display a "point" into your `UIView` and you need to control it, just add a child `UIView` to your parent `UIView` having a frame of 1px square with a color background (if you need to display it). In this case any spatial modification to your parent UIView will affect the child `UIView` (even rotation).

Otherwise, if you need to know the position of a `CGPoint` rotate by an angle relative to another point, please refer to this nice answer that contains the math you need.

[Rotate a point by another point in 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786472/rotate-a-point-by-an-angle)

Ciao!