# C - Graphics, Unable to rotate a polygon

Tags: c, bgi, turbo-c

In the below program I am trying to rotate the triangle by 45 degree anti-cockwise. The polygon did rotate to some angle and translated to some other place. Please let me know how this can be fixed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
 int poly[8], rpoly[8],angle;
 int gd = DETECT, gm;
 initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TC\\BGI");

 printf("\n Enter co-ordinates for Triangle :  \n\n");

 printf("Vertex 1 (x,y)  : ");
 scanf("%d %d", &poly[0], &poly[1]);
 printf("Vertex 2 (x,y)  : ");
 scanf("%d %d", &poly[2], &poly[3]);
 printf("Vertex 3 (x,y)  : ");
 scanf("%d %d", &poly[4], &poly[5]);
 poly[6] = poly[0];
 poly[7] = poly[1];

 setcolor(2);
 drawpoly(4,poly);

 angle = 45;
 rpoly[0] = poly[0]*cos(angle) - poly[1]*sin(angle);
 rpoly[1] = poly[0]*sin(angle) + poly[1]*cos(angle);

 rpoly[2] = poly[2]*cos(angle) - poly[3]*sin(angle);
 rpoly[3] = poly[2]*sin(angle) + poly[3]*cos(angle);

 rpoly[4] = poly[4]*cos(angle) - poly[5]*sin(angle);
 rpoly[5] = poly[4]*sin(angle) + poly[5]*cos(angle);

 rpoly[6] = rpoly[0];
 rpoly[7] = rpoly[1];

 setcolor(4);
 drawpoly(4,rpoly);

 getch();
 closegraph();
 return 0;
}
```

Output: 
[image]

EDIT 1:

In the Output the Red Triangle (i.e Triangle after Rotation) looks bigger than the original one.

New Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
 int poly[8], rpoly[8], angle, centroid_x, centroid_y,i;
 int gd = DETECT, gm;
 initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TC\\BGI");

 printf("\n Enter co-ordinates for Triangle :  \n\n");

 printf("Vertex 1 (x,y)  : ");
 scanf("%d %d", &poly[0], &poly[1]);
 printf("Vertex 2 (x,y)  : ");
 scanf("%d %d", &poly[2], &poly[3]);
 printf("Vertex 3 (x,y)  : ");
 scanf("%d %d", &poly[4], &poly[5]);
 poly[6] = poly[0];
 poly[7] = poly[1];

 setcolor(2);
 drawpoly(4,poly);

 angle = 45 * 2 * 3.14 / 360;
 centroid_x =  (poly[0] + poly[2] + poly[4]) / 3;
 centroid_y =  (poly[1] + poly[3] + poly[5]) / 3;

 rpoly[0] = (poly[0] - centroid_x) * cos(angle)  -  (poly[1] - centroid_y) * sin(angle)  +  centroid_x;
 rpoly[1] = (poly[0] - centroid_x) * sin(angle)  -  (poly[1] - centroid_y) * cos(angle)  +  centroid_y;

 rpoly[2] = (poly[2] - centroid_x) * cos(angle)  -  (poly[3] - centroid_y) * sin(angle)  +  centroid_x;
 rpoly[3] = (poly[2] - centroid_x) * sin(angle)  -  (poly[3] - centroid_y) * cos(angle)  +  centroid_y;

 rpoly[4] = (poly[4] - centroid_x) * cos(angle)  -  (poly[5] - centroid_y) * sin(angle)  +  centroid_x;
 rpoly[5] = (poly[4] - centroid_x) * sin(angle)  -  (poly[5] - centroid_y) * cos(angle)  +  centroid_y;

 rpoly[6] = rpoly[0];
 rpoly[7] = rpoly[1];

 setcolor(4);
 drawpoly(4,rpoly);

 for(i=0;i<7;i++)
 {printf("\n %d", &rpoly[i]);}

 getch();
 closegraph();
 return 0;
}
```

OutPut:
[image]

EDIT 2:

Code after correcting the Y - terms:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
 int poly[8], rpoly[8], angle, centroid_x, centroid_y,i;
 int gd = DETECT, gm;
 initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TC\\BGI");

 printf("\n Enter co-ordinates for Triangle :  \n\n");

 printf("Vertex 1 (x,y)  : ");
 scanf("%d %d", &poly[0], &poly[1]);
 printf("Vertex 2 (x,y)  : ");
 scanf("%d %d", &poly[2], &poly[3]);
 printf("Vertex 3 (x,y)  : ");
 scanf("%d %d", &poly[4], &poly[5]);
 poly[6] = poly[0];
 poly[7] = poly[1];

 setcolor(2);
 drawpoly(4,poly);

 angle = 45 * 2 * 3.14 / 360;
 centroid_x =  (poly[0] + poly[2] + poly[4]) / 3;
 centroid_y =  (poly[1] + poly[3] + poly[5]) / 3;

 rpoly[0] = (poly[0] - centroid_x) * cos(angle)  -  (poly[1] - centroid_y) * sin(angle)  +  centroid_x;
 rpoly[1] = (poly[0] - centroid_x) * sin(angle)  +  (poly[1] - centroid_y) * cos(angle)  +  centroid_y;

 rpoly[2] = (poly[2] - centroid_x) * cos(angle)  -  (poly[3] - centroid_y) * sin(angle)  +  centroid_x;
 rpoly[3] = (poly[2] - centroid_x) * sin(angle)  +  (poly[3] - centroid_y) * cos(angle)  +  centroid_y;

 rpoly[4] = (poly[4] - centroid_x) * cos(angle)  -  (poly[5] - centroid_y) * sin(angle)  +  centroid_x;
 rpoly[5] = (poly[4] - centroid_x) * sin(angle)  +  (poly[5] - centroid_y) * cos(angle)  +  centroid_y;

 rpoly[6] = rpoly[0];
 rpoly[7] = rpoly[1];

 setcolor(4);
 drawpoly(4,rpoly);

// for(i=0;i<8;i++)
// {printf("\n %d", &rpoly[i]);}

 getch();
 closegraph();
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Two problems: `sin` and `cos` take arguments in *radians*, not degrees; and you probably want to rotate your polygon about its centre, not about (0, 0).

To fix the first problem, change:

```
angle = 45;
```

to:

```
angle = 45.0 * 2.0 * M_PI / 360.0;
```

To fix the second problem you need to first calculate the centroid of your polygon, then do your translations of the coordinates of the vertices relative to the centroid.

Comment: How do I rotate it about its centre ?

Comment: What does M_PI stand for ? Is that a Keyword ?

Comment: Failed_Noob, Paul R already said "...you need to first calculate the centroid of your polygon." [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) has several algorithms listed. Or, for a simple triangle, you could use x = (Ax + Bx + Cx) / 3, y = (Ay + By + Cy) / 3

Comment: M_PI is just a constant for Pi.

Comment: A doubt... will it work if I rotate each point using the formula provided by Ben [Here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786472/rotate-a-point-by-an-angle)

Comment: Yes, that should work, but note that you still need to calculate the centroid since this will give you ox, oy, i.e. the point about which you are going to perform the rotation.

Comment: I pasted the new code along with its output. Please have a look.

Comment: But in Ben's answer it is given as `p'x = cos(theta) * (px-ox) - sin(theta) * (py-oy) + ox`

Comment: Also ` rpoly[6] = rpoly[0];
 rpoly[7] = rpoly[1];
` but in the output values for rpoly[6] and rpoly[7] are wrong. Even after I make `for(i=0;i<8;i++)
`

Comment: My bad - I did some quick "back of the envelope" geometry and over-simplified. Use Ben's formulae.

Comment: Note that it looks like you have a mistake in your Y terms - you need a `+` instead of a `-`.

Comment: Corrected the Y-terms and now the triangle looks elongated o.O. See output

Answer (score 4):

```
 rpoly[0] = (poly[0] - centroid_x) * cos(angle)  -  (poly[1] - centroid_y) * sin(angle)  +  centroid_x;
 rpoly[1] = (poly[0] - centroid_x) * sin(angle)  +  (poly[1] - centroid_y) * cos(angle)  +  centroid_y;
```

rpoly[1] is calculated after rpoly[0] has been changed.

try this;

```
float newX = .......;
rpoly[0] = newX;
float newY = .......;
rpoly[1] = newY;
```